# It`s split pot if

Tags: texas-hold-em, rules, poker-theory, odds

If is A 2 3 4 5 heart down. X have 6 7 heart and Y have 8 9 heart . It's split pot becouse is A down or Y win?

Comment: The best 5 Card combination of boards cards and hand cards win the hand. A straight from Ace to 5 is on the board, Player X has a straight flush from three to seven. Player Y has a straight flush on the board from A to 5, which means player X wins the hand.

Comment: X's best five-card hand is 3h-4h-5h-6h-7h, a 7-high straight flush. Y's best hand is Ah-2h-3h-4h-5h, a 5-high straight flush. X wins.